# Deploying service to remote web server throws exception: 'There was an error deserializing the object of type XXXX'

Tags: c#, wcf

I've seen a few questions answered on this subject but none seem to match my scenario.

I have a local ASP.NET MVC app that's connecting to a local development instance of a WFC service. If I send a large string param to the local development service, everything is fine.  When I deploy that exact same service to my remote web server, I get the following error (where XXXX is a namespaced object in the service):

> "The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:FormPost. The InnerException message was 'There was an error deserializing the object of type XXXX. The maximum string content length quota (8192) has been exceeded while reading XML data. This quota may be increased by changing the MaxStringContentLength property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader. Line 1, position 10304."

Here's the odd thing:

1. The codebase on my local service (on localhost) and on the remote service (at www.MyUrl.com) are exactly the same.  Yet when I switch my client app (running on localhost) between them I only get the error on the remote service, not the local.
2. When I change the `MaxStringContentLength` property value to say 2147483647 on my local client, it makes no difference.  And the endpoint is definitely using the correct binding name.

   ```
   <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ITheService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
         openTimeout="01:10:00" receiveTimeout="01:10:00" sendTimeout="01:10:00"
         allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
         maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
         textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
         <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" **maxStringContentLength="8192"** maxArrayLength="16384"
           maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
         <security mode="None">
           <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
             realm="" />
           <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
         </security>
       </binding>

   <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ITheService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
         openTimeout="01:10:00" receiveTimeout="01:10:00" sendTimeout="01:10:00"
         allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
         maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
         textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
         <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" **maxStringContentLength="2147483647"** maxArrayLength="16384"
           maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
         <security mode="None">
           <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
             realm="" />
           <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
         </security>
       </binding>
   ```
3. There is no binding configuration in the service-side web.config file to change. It is only on the client.  Yet the error is referring to a failure to deserialize an object that is a service-side class.

Comment: If there is no binding on the service side web.config, then you are getting the default value for `maxStringContentLength` for `basicHttpBinding` - which is 8192.  You'll need to add a binding configuration with larger values, and you can set it as the default by ommitting the `name` attribute on the `binding` element.